# О сочинительной и подчинительной связи в сложных предложениях

Tags: грамматика, недопустимая-метка

В связи с недавним спором на эту тему мне хотелось бы поделиться с вами некоторыми мыслями о предложениях С ОДНОРОДНЫМ СОПОДЧИНЕНИЕМ. Идея состоит в том, что структуры более высокого порядка (в данном случае СПП) могут изменять  статус входящих структур(в нашем случае сочинительную связь однородных предложений).

Пример 1. БСП: ДОЖДИК КОНЧИЛСЯ, ТУЧА ПОШЛА ДАЛЬШЕ. При построении БСП используются два простых предложения:  Дождик↑кончился↓.   Туча пошла ↑дальше.↓  Простое  (неосложненное) предложение состоит из двух фраз: восходящий тон и нисходящий тон. (Фраза – это речевой отрезок, имеющий тоническое ударение, то есть повышение или понижение тона на ударном слоге одного из слов, входящих во фразу). Получает такой своеобразный «домик».

Теперь мы хотим соединить эти два предложения, чтобы получить БСП. Интонационная схема такого предложения следующая: Дождик↑кончился↓, туча пошла ↑дальше.↓ Мы видим, что интонация исходных предложений сохранена – получается «волна» восходящих и нисходящих фраз (всего 4 фразы). Это ПЕРЕЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНАЯ ИНТОНАЦИЯ, выражающая СОЧИНИТЕЛЬНУЮ СВЯЗЬ между простыми предложениями в составе БСП.

Пример 2. СПП: ТЕПЕРЬ И Я ВИДЕЛ, ЧТО ДОЖДИК КОНЧИЛСЯ, ТУЧА УХОДИТ ДАЛЬШЕ. Интонационная схема: Теперь и я видел↑, что дождик кончился↑, туча уходит дальше.↓ Всего в СПП три фразы. ПЕРЕЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНАЯ ИНТОНАЦИЯ ОТСУТСТВУЕТ,  каждое из двух самостоятельных предложений, ранее состоящих из двух фраз,  превращается в одну фразу (с одним тоническим ударением) –  «домик» как бы выпрямляется.

Таким образом, мы видим, как сочинительная связь независимых предложений, входящих в  БСП,  КАЧЕСТВЕННО МЕНЯЕТСЯ, ОТХОДИТ НА ВТОРОЙ ПЛАН, когда те же предложения входят в СПП.  Теперь интонацию новой конструкции задает ПОДЧИНИТЕЛЬНАЯ СВЯЗЬ, именно на ней строится интонационная структура СПП.

Также можно сделать ВЫВОД, что статус простых предложений, входящих в состав СПП понижается:  они ведут себя как однородные члены. Это СОЧИНИТЕЛЬНАЯ СВЯЗЬ, как и в случае однородных членов, но в СПП она НЕ ВЫРАЖЕНА С ПОМОЩЬЮ ПЕРЕЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОЙ ИНТОНАЦИИ и поэтому НЕ УЧИТЫВАЕТСЯ ПРИ РАЗБОРЕ. Сравнить: ТЕПЕРЬ И Я ВИДЕЛ ↑, ЧТО НЕБО СВЕТЛЕЕТ↑, СТАНОВИТСЯ ГОЛУБЫМ↓  – точно такую интонационную структуру  из трех фраз, как и СПП,  имеет предложение с однородными членами.

ВЫВОДЫ

1. Сложное предложение – это действительно ПРИНЦИПИАЛЬНО НОВАЯ КОНСТРУКЦИЯ со своей собственной структурой и интонацией. Грамматику сложных предложений различные ученые рассматривают неоднозначно. Основной вопрос состоит в том, является ли сложное предложение качественно новой синтаксической конструкцией или простые предложения, входящие в сложное,  сохраняют свою самостоятельность. Интонационный анализ показывает нам, что верна, скорее, первая точка зрения.
2. Становится понятной причина недавнего спора на форуме, а также разные высказывания в Интернете на эту тему. При однородном соподчинении ОДНОРОДНЫЕ ПРИДАТОЧНЫЕ СВЯЗАНЫ МЕЖДУ СОБОЙ БЕССОЮЗНО ИЛИ С ПОМОЩЬЮ СОЮЗОВ, НО ЭТА СВЯЗЬ НЕ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ЗНАЧИМОЙ, НЕ УЧИТЫВАЕТСЯ ПРИ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИИ ВИДА ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ – то есть мы не можем сказать, что перед нами сложное предложение с  подчинением и сочинением – это просто сложноподчиненное предложение  с однородными придаточными.
3. А вот пример сложного предложения С  ПОДЧИНЕНИЕМ И СОЧИНЕНИЕМ: Теперь и я увидел↑, что  дождик кончился↑, но  ехать в город ↑ мне было еще рано.↓ Оно состоит из  СПП и простого предложения, которые связаны между собой сочинительным союзом НО. Отметим, что простое предложение имеет собственную  (независимую) интонационную структуру, состоящую из двух фраз.

Comment: Как только Вы подставите второй союз "что", перечислительная интонация вернется.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду: Теперь и я увидел↑, что дождик↑ кончился↓, ↓ что туча пошла↑ дальше.↓ Я, кстати, прослушивала для себя такой вариант - он, с первого взгляда, кажется возможным. Но, в действительности, он не точный, так как  требует понижения тона после слова "кончился", а это внутри предложения невозможно, иначе нарушается целостность СПП.

Comment: Теперь↑ и я увидел↓/ что дождик↑ кончился↓/  что туча↑ пошла дальше↓/ -если Вы используете актуальное членение на синтагмы, нужно соблюдать интонационное членение на  тему и рему. Теперь↑ и я увидел↓/ что дождик кончился↓// но ехать в город ↑ мне было еще рано/ Однако нужно учитывать(и ставить в схеме) и логическое или фразовое ударение, а Вы совместили его с повышением/понижением тона. Это неверно.

Answer (score 1):

София, во-первых,у Вас не вопрос, а выводы после обсуждения. По-моему, их лучше выставить на обсуждение в рубрике "ИССЛЕДОВАНИЯ".

Во-вторых,стала вдумываться в Ваши размышления.С Вашим интонационным членением я не согласна. Попробовала прочитать по Вашим схемам - не получилось.

1) Вы как-то синтагму странно разделили.Туча-тема, пошла дальше - рема.
Значит, должно быть так:Дождик↑кончился↓// Туча↑ пошла дальше↓//

2)БСС: Дождик↑кончился↓/ туча↑ пошла дальше↓//-интонация перечисления.

3)СПП: Теперь↑ и я видел↓ / что дождик↑ кончился↓ / туча↑ уходит дальше↓//-интонация перечисления  остаётся между 2 и 3 фрагментами.

Теперь и я видел↑/ что дождик кончился  и туча уходит дальше↓//-интонация СОЕДИНЕНИЯ между 2 и 3 фрагментами.

В-третьих,сочинительная связь выражается не только интонацией перечисления, но и интонацией разделения, противопоставления, в зависимости от союза.

В-четвёртых, я и пыталась сказать, что в СПП важна связь между главным и придаточным, а между придаточными устанавливается ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНАЯ СОЧИНИТЕЛЬНАЯ  связь, если между ними сочинительный   союз, в остальных случаях связи нет, в СПП- последовательное подчинение и СОподчинение.

Comment: 1. В середине СПП не может быть нисходящей фразы - иначе интонация перечисления , а вместе с ней и сочинительная связь,  сохранятся. Думаю, что такое чтение некорректно, хотя возможно.Но тогда мы не получим качественно новой структуры. Перестройка интонация - это обязательное свойство при повышении сложности предложений.
2. При появлении союза "И" СПП будет состоять из двух фраз, как вы указываете.
3. С последним утверждением я не могу согласиться - однородные придаточные связаны бессоюзно или союзами, но связаны по принципу однородных членов. Об этом пишут и в Интернете.

Comment: Принцип-то однородных членов, но связь бессоюзная и союзная.Это союзы дают интонацию перечисления, соединения, разделения, противоположения, сопоставления и т.д.

Comment: И потом, София,Интернет - понятие широкое - научные работы, справочники, профессиональные форумы, дилетантские форумы(тётя Маша сказала...) Нужно  давать ссылку, кто сказал.

Comment: Если взять тему однородных членов, то там интонацию меняют только соединительные и разделительные одиночные союзы (они соединяют два однородных члена в одну фразу) - при наличии остальных союзов и при бессоюзной связи интонация сохраняется.

Comment: Видимо, Вы всё-таки говорите не об интонации, а о ритмике, паузах, интонация - то везде разная, она не может сохраняться при остальных союзах, союзы дают разную интонацию, потому мы и не можем понять друг друга. Мы говорим о разных вещах.

Comment: Возможно. Я пользуюсь упрощенными интонационными моделями, туда входят только основные понятия: фраза, синтагма, пауза, темп речи. Их удобно применять при решении пунктуационных задач.